# Convert mcrypt used in PHP to Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, mcrypt

I want to convert this code to Node.js:

```
<?php
$str = 'test';
$key = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TripleDES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
$ret = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
mcrypt_module_close($td);
$ret = base64_encode($ret);
echo($ret);
```

output: 7YM5liyGmBs=

Coded like this with Node.js:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const str = 'test'
const key = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
const iv = ''
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3', key, iv)
let res = `${cipher.update(str, 'utf8', 'base64')}${cipher.final('base64')}`
console.log(res)
```

output: kSSvwld1yDA=

Why is the output different, and how should I code it in Node.js?

Comment: I think variable `iv` has a different value.

Comment: What value should I set?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. On PHP-side you set the iv (correctly) with a random value ("$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);"). You should be able to generate a random iv on node-js as well. Just keep in mind that you will receive definitely other encrypted outputs each time you run your encryption function -:).